# POST in REST API - JSON can't serialize my data

Tags: python, rest

I'm trying to POST some data through REST API. However, with the following code, the program refuses to abide (added fluff for readability):

```
def Actions(self, imei, name):
    global addAttribute
    if addAttribute == True:
        attributes = {"decoder.timezone":"Etc/GMT"}
    else:
        attributes = ""
    url = "https://example.com/api/devices/"
    data = {"name":name, "uniqueId":imei, "attributes":attributes}
    print("data not transformed:")
    print(data)
    print()
    data_json = json.dumps(data)
    print("data transformed by json.dumps():")
    print(data_json)
    print()
    test = requests.post(url, auth=('mylogin', 'pwd'), json=data_json)
    print(test.content)
```

The console says:

```
data not transformed:
{'name': 'Example 1', 'uniqueId': 'Example 1', 'attributes': {'decoder.timezone': 'Etc/GMT'}}

data transformed by json.dumps():
{"name": "Example 1", "uniqueId": "Example 1", "attributes": {"decoder.timezone": "Etc/GMT"}}

b'Cannot construct instance of `org.traccar.model.Device` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value (\'{"name": "Example 1",     "uniqueId": "Example 1", "attributes": {"decoder.timezone": "Etc/GMT"}}\')\n at [Source: (org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]'
```

Perhaps I should express my data differently, rather than as a dictionary? If so, how?

Comment: @Thecave3 Yes, it essentially responds with the same thing: https://pastebin.com/sFmMFB2N

Comment: Are u sure about attribute as an object?

Comment: @Thecave3 I even removed the "attributes" part to see if it changes anything - it unfortunately didn't

Comment: try not use `json.dumps()` method.  `json` param  accept dict params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `requests` [documentation](https://2.python-requests.org//en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), the field `json` is for `dict` objects and the field `data` is for `string` objects.

You're passing a `string` in the field of a `dict`. You may want to do something like this:

```
 data = {"name":name, "uniqueId":imei, "attributes":attributes}  
 data_json = json.dumps(data)  
 test = requests.post(url, auth=('mylogin', 'pwd'), data=data_json)
 print(test.content)
```

or something like this:

```
 data = {"name":name, "uniqueId":imei, "attributes":attributes}
 test = requests.post(url, auth=('mylogin', 'pwd'), json=data)
 print(test.content)
```

They should both work, but you should probably choose the second one because the `json.dump` operation it is done inside the post request.